Можно ли полностью заменить содержимое одной таблицы на содержимое другой без предварительного удаления содержимого таблицы-приемника
Задача полностью скопировать одну таблицу в другую, при этом в таблице-приемнике есть данные, которые должны быть полностью заменены на новые. Т. е., старые данные должны быть стерты и заменены на новые. Аналогии с операционной системой подсказывали мне, что должен быть запрос, который просто перезапишет одну таблицу поверх другой (т.е., если мы один файл копируем в другой, то нам не надо заботится о том, что находится в файле-приемнике, он просто будет перезаписан). Однако, я не нашел подобной механики. Надо либо дропнуть приемник и создать его заново с копированием источника:
DROP TABLE dest;
CREATE TABLE dest AS TABLE source;

либо удалить содержимое приемника и скопировать содержимое источника:
TRUNCATE TABLE dest;
INSERT INTO dest (fields) SELECT fields FROM source;

Два вопроса:

Существует ли способ обновить данные без предварительного стирания предыдущих.
Если такого способа нет, то какой из предложенных мной способов лучше и чем? Возможно существует еще какой-то?


хорошенько определитесь с тем, по какому критерию будете сравнивать "есть данные, которые должны быть полностью заменены на новые" с собственно новыми данными, и напишите запрос с использованием команды MERGE (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/sql-merge).

@RabbanKeyak Возможно, в каком-то частном случае merge into может сработать, но в общем - нет. Поясню. Допустим (на самом деле так и есть), у меня в каждой записи содержится уникальное поле идентификатор, по которому можно проверять условие для мержа. Есть три варианта наличия/отсутствия идентификатора в новой и старой таблице. 1. Идентификатор есть в обеих. Обрабатываем when match then do nothing.  2 В новой есть, в старой нет. Обрабатываем when not match insert… 3. В старой есть в новой нет. Надо удалять. Мержем не выйдет. В любом случае, проще все удалить и обновить.


В PostgreSQL нет прямого способа "обновить" содержимое одной таблицы содержимым другой без предварительного удаления данных в таблице-приемнике.

Из предложенных вами способов лучше TRUNCATE TABLE ...; с последующим INSERT INTO ... (...)SELECT ... FROM ...;
2.1 Сохранение структуры: TRUNCATE TABLE  удаляет все данные из таблицы, но сохраняет ее структуру (ограничения, индексы, триггеры). Это важно, если таблица участвует в каких-либо зависимостях или имеет сложную структуру. DROP TABLE  удалит всю таблицу, включая ее структуру.
2.2 Скорость:  В большинстве случаев TRUNCATE TABLE  работает быстрее, чем DROP TABLE с последующим CREATE TABLE. Это связано с тем, что TRUNCATE TABLE просто удаляет записи, не записывая их в журнал транзакций. Особенно это заметно для больших таблиц.

Альтернативный (не оптимальный) способ, почти тоже самое что и пункт 2


DELETE FROM dest;
INSERT INTO dest (id, fields) SELECT id, fields FROM source;

P.S. в некоторых случаях DROP TABLE с последующим CREATE TABLE  может быть более эффективным, например, если вам необходимо скопировать данные из таблицы с одной схемой в другую схему. В таких случаях создание новой таблицы может быть быстрее, чем INSERT  в существующую таблицу.
P.P.S. На всякий случай прикладываю документацию по командам postgrespro
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/sql-droptable
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/sql-createtable
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/sql-truncate
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/sql-delete

Дисклеймер: я уже выбрал лучший ответ, однако, я нашел альтернативное решение, которое, по моему мнению, может пригодиться не только мне. Мне оно помогло, поэтому оставлю его здесь
Альтернативой таблице-приемнику может стать так называемое материализованное представление - Materialized view - слепок данных из таблицы-источника, который может быть как полной таблицей, так и выборкой. В этом случае, мы сначала создаем представление:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW dest
AS TABLE source;

или для выборки
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW dest
AS SELECT … FROM source …;

и после этого, в момент когда нам необходимо перезаписать старое содержимое новым применяем:
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW dest;

Также оставлю здесь ссылку на мой вопрос о разнице между временной таблицей и materialized view - в ответе подробно описана разница.

Оператор MERGE вставит новые, заменит конфликты, но оставит без изменения то что нет в таблице обновления. Удобен например для обновления частями.

В моей задаче как раз важно, чтобы таблица-приемник полностью соответствовал таблице-источнику, поэтому важным недостатком мержа (в контексте данной задачи) является то, что он никуда не денет то, что есть в приемнике, но нет в источнике. Все равно как-то придется удалять эти остатки.
